# Overloading std::swap() using CRTP

Tags: c++, c++11, swap, crtp

Ok I have two classes, `matrix_row` and `matrix_column`, which (as their names say) represent rows and columns of matrices. I'm doing this to do operations between matrix rows/columns ("Lines") in an easy way. Something like `m1.row(1) = m1.column(0) + m2.row(7)`.

Since the two types of lines are almost the same thing, except of the way to access the underlying elements, I have a CRTP base class holding all the operations. Then the two classes menctioned above inherit from it and specify its own way to access an element through static dispatch:

```
template<typename T , std::size_t ROWS , std::size_t COLUMNS , typename DERIVED>
struct line
{
    std::reference_wrapper<matrix<T,ROWS,COLUMNS>> ref;
    std::size_t index;

    ...
};

template<typename T , std::size_t ROWS , std::size_t COLUMNS>
struct matrix_row : public line<T,ROWS,COLUMNS,matrix_row<T,ROWS,COLUMNS>>
{
    const T& at( std::size_t index ) const { return this->matrix_ref.get()[this->index][index]; }
          T& at( std::size_t index )       { return this->matrix_ref.get()[this->index][index]; }  

    using base_t::operator=;
};

template<typename T , std::size_t ROWS , std::size_t COLUMNS>
struct matrix_column : public line<T,ROWS,COLUMNS,matrix_column<T,ROWS,COLUMNS>>
{
    const T& at( std::size_t index ) const { return this->matrix_ref.get()[index][this->index]; }
          T& at( std::size_t index )       { return this->matrix_ref.get()[index][this->index]; }  

    using base_t::operator=;
};
```

Everything seems to work until here, assigment between different types of lines included. Now I want to overload `std::swap()` for lines, for algorithms that require matrix line swapping (Like Gaussian elimination for example). So I have added a `swap()` function in my own namespace:

```
template<typename LHS_T , typename RHS_T , 
         std::size_t LHS_Rs , std::size_t RHS_Rs ,
         std::size_t LHS_Cs , std::size_t RHS_Cs ,
         typename LHS_D , typename RHS_D
        >         
friend void swap( line<LHS_T,LHS_Rs,LHS_Cs,LHS_D>& lhs , line<RHS_T,RHS_Rs,RHS_Cs,RHS_D>& rhs )
{
    assert( lhs.length == rhs.length );

    for( std::size_t i = 0 ; i < lhs.length ; ++i )
        std::swap( lhs[i] , rhs[i] );
}
```

Since I need different line types to be swapable (Exchange one column of a matrix with one row of the same length, for example), I defined the function to work with the base instead of the derived types.

I have two questions:

- All the machinery is on the base class, the derived classes only serve to provide a custom access (`at()`) method. **I'm incurring on slicing problems doing swap on this way even if the memory layout of the derived classes is (Thats what I understand since there is no `virtual` nor extra data members) the same as the layout of the base?**
- When using that `swap()` template, the compiler complains with `no known conversion from [derived] to [base]&` errors. **What I'm missing? Why is a conversion needed if I'm using references to the base class?**

Comment: What about the usual `static_cast<DERIVED*>(this)` casting in the base class?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ its part of the elipsis... ;)

Comment: I should mention that I think this is a bad idea.  swapping two types should not be allowed, because if you have a row and a column, and swap their data, the row does not become a column.

Comment: @MooingDuck I think that depends on the point of view. Viewing things like values thats true, since as you said a row does not become a column. But viewing objects as resource managers (handlers) this makes sense: `std::swap()` becomes resource swapping (*"Take mine and give me yours"*). And thats the case I'm trying to accomplish, where the "resources" are the underlying elements referenced by the matrix rows and columns.

Comment: If you're using the ADL + `using std::swap` technique to call this `swap` function for at least one object of a derived type, then `std::swap` will be a better match, and this function will call some copy/move operations. (Unfortunately, there's no inheritance mechanism for `swap`.)

Comment: @dyp I think thats an answer to my question ;) Indeed, supose it works: Using the references in that way lead into silcing issues?